# Clean code with svg.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, svg.js

I am making a resume in HTML5 with the help of svg.js. I have made 5 labels like this:

```
var las = lang.text(function(add){
  add.tspan('Läsa').dx(178).dy(145)
})
```

same thing for `tal, skr, lys` and `ord`

To make as DRY code as possible I then style them like this:

```
var labels = [las, tal, skr, lys, ord]
labels.forEach(function(lab){
  lab.font({
    family: 'Helvetica',
    size: 18
  })
})
```

Now, my question is mostly about style, but what are the ways to go about this?

What I *would* like to do is just call `forEach` directly on the array without having to clutter with variables, like this:

```
[las, tal, skr, lys, ord].forEach(function(lab){
  lab.font({
    family: 'Helvetica',
    size: 18
  })
})
```

But that doesn't work, although I don't really understand why. The MDN article for the error message doesn't make me any wiser. Sorry if this question seems silly, but either my google-fu isn't good enough or this really is so silly that no one bothered to ask it before :P

Comment: Please add a fiddle so we can debug whats going wrong

Comment: Add a ";" before the array literal. When you remove the newlines your code reads `somefunction()[your Array liteal]` - the parser trys acces an index which isnt there. Therefore the error message you (most likely) get. But without fiddle or further code its just tryharding